# How to purchase a new catapult?

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-3

When the catapult of one of my heroes is destroyed (e.g. because of a sufficiently powerful Armageddon spell during a siege), how can I purchase a new one for him/her? Is there any town structure where I can do that, or any structure on the world map (like the War Machine Factory, which unfortunately only sells the other three: Ballista, Ammo Cart and First Aid Tent)? Or is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The catapult only appears in siege combat, and can only attack castle walls and other fortifications. Every hero has **one**, it cannot be **sold**, given away, unequipped, or left behind, and if the catapult is destroyed during combat, it will reappear once the combat phase is over.

So from that I assume that you can't buy another one.

[Link to were quote is from](http://mightandmagic.wikia.com/wiki/Catapult)

Comment: Ah, you might be right, but note that the quote is written in a place where it's valid for *all* versions of Heroes. I'm not sure if that was intended. I vaguely remembered this being an issue when I played the game 15 years ago, but I had an unpatched version (e.g. where you didn't need gems to buy angels). I'll try to recreate the scenario on the iPad app and let you (and future readers) know what happens.

Comment: In Heroes of Might and Magic 3 (at least the Complete edition, which has both the Armageddon's Blade and The Shadow of Death expansions), you get a "new" catapult for free after a battle. That is, the catapult is not destroyed permanently and will reappear in the next combat. However, it is possible for the catapult to be destroyed and the current combat becoming unwinnable if you have no way to cross the walls or attack beyond them.

Comment: @mmKALLL if you read above it says that right there "if the catapult is destroyed during combat, it will reappear once the combat phase is over".

Comment: @Emptyisme Yes, but as it seems like there was confusion over which game exactly works like this I decided to specify how it is in HoMM3. In hindsight, just noting that it works as described in the answer would have been sufficient. Unfortunately I am unable to edit the comment anymore.

Comment: I just tested it, and while the catapult is listed as a 'casualty' after the battle, it automatically reappears in the hero's inventory. P.S. no Black Dragons were harmed during this experiment - they're immune to Armageddon.

Comment: I remember, how I unluckily lured some very strong enemy hero with weak Roland, at the beginning of one of Armageddon's Blade campaign early scenarios. Enemy had many times more units than me, but I think could command towers. I somehow got lucky, when it goes to destroying the walls and it did like only a single hole, in which I could defend myself, before I managed to destroy catapult. I barely won, then saved the game and loaded autosave.... I tried at least 40-50 times and it always did too much damage for me to win. I was so lucky the first try. One of most epic defenses ever!